# Convert data frame from long to wide format with nested column headers in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c("2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2020","2020","2020"),
      Sex = c("F", "M", "X","F", "M", "X","F", "M", "X"),
      Data1 = c("1", "4", "5", "3", "6", "8", "23", "2", "456"),
      Data2 = c("14", "34", "588", "6", "75", "3", "2", "62", "406"))
```

and I want it to end up in this format:

```
     |    2018   |   2019    |   2020    |     
     | F | M | X | F | M | X | F | M | X |  
Data1| 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 23| 2 | 46|  
Data2| 14| 34|588| 6 | 75| 3 | 2 | 62|406|
```

I know I can get the long table into wide format using `pivot_wider` from the tidyverse, but I am not sure how to get the nested headers. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds as if you want to export your data as a table. In that case I would suggest to have a look at one of the packages for creating tables, e.g. `flextable` provides `separate_header()` which makes it easy to create a nested header.

Comment: `gt` package also allows for nested headers as well now (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823339/3460670))